# MicroStrategy REST API 2021 Cube Datasource / History

Tags: api, rest, microstrategy

I've been digging through the 2021 MicroStrategy API trying to find a few specific things. Hopefully someone knows where I could find the data, or just tell me it's not there so I can stop looking.

This is what I'm looking for:

1. I'm looking to be able to see what Data Sources are enabled for a cube. In the 2021 API, I'm now able to view the sql (/api/v2/cubes/{cubeId}/sqlView) but I can't find anywhere to view the Data Source that sql is being run on.
2. Is there a way to to get the data stored in the "History List"? I'm looking to count the number of cubes in Error status.

Comment: Did you manage to find a way to access the history list?

Comment: @Narshe, unfortunately I was not :(